# How to respond to Task Module or task/fetch in Bot framework v4 using Node JS without TeamsActivityHandler?

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

In Teams, I need to populate a Task Module with a web page using NodeJS and BotBuilder 4.8. Once the Bot detected the Invoke from a AdaptiveCard with a "msteams": { "type": "task/fetch"}:

[image: Screenshot]

`if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Invoke) { ...`

I can't figure out how to respond with a HTTP 200 status, with the content type and body like:

```
{
    "task": {
      "type": "continue",
      "value": {
        "title": "My Title",
        "height": 200,
        "width": 500,
        "url": "[myURL]",
        "fallbackUrl": "[myURL]"
      }
    }
  }
```

as documented at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/create-task-module?tabs=javascript

I can't extend from TeamsActivityHandler.

I even tried:

```
const botbuilder_core_1 = require("botbuilder-core");
return botbuilder_core_1.ActivityHandler.createInvokeResponse(myBody);
```

which throws **[Adapter onTurnError]: Error: ContentType of an attachment is not set**

Is there a MessageFactory class or similar that can simply send a response back?

The sample at https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/54.teams-task-module/bots/teamsTaskModuleBot.js is not enough for me.

```
Bot.js
if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Invoke) {
    // Handler for Adaptive Cards actions 
    if (turnContext.activity.value != undefined && turnContext.activity.value.id != undefined) {
    switch (turnContext.activity.value.id) {
        case "openOfficesMaps":
            await this.findOfficesAdressesDialog.displayMaps(turnContext);
            break;
        ...

class FindOfficesAdressesDialog extends SalesHubComponentDialog {
    async displayMaps(turnContext) {
        // If it were an adaptive card I would do this:
        return await turnContext.sendActivity({
            attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(officesMapTaskModule)]
        });

officesMapTaskModule.json
{
    "task": {
      "type": "continue",
      "value": {
        "title": "Offices Map",
        "height": 500,
        "width": "medium",
        "url": "[myURL]/$24web/officesMapTaskModule.html",
        "fallbackUrl": "[myURL]/%24web/officesMapTaskModule.html"
      }
    }
  }

class FindOfficesAdressesDialog extends SalesHubComponentDialog {
    async displayMaps(turnContext) {
        // This gives content type is missing
        const botbuilder_core_1 = require("botbuilder-core");
        return botbuilder_core_1.ActivityHandler.createInvokeResponse(body);
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need `TeamsActivityHandler`. Why can't you extend from it like the sample? Please include your full code for your ActivityHandler.

Comment: The sample makes the entire Bot be declared like:

class TeamsTaskModuleBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {

It's not a good design to make the entire bot to extend from a handler of a certain channel, just because one dialogue needs to show a popup. In my case, class FindOfficesAdressesDialog already extends from another class, may I need to solve multi-inheritance in nodejs for addressing it? Thanks in advance @mdrichardson

Comment: Ah. I see. `TeamsActivityHandler` is just additional handlers for Teams, but it still supports all of the normal `ActivityHandler`s without overwriting any. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/cfca7118b2e0b2f75242d22b8af0a5d82a1560ba/libraries/botbuilder/src/teamsActivityHandler.ts). You can use it and still use the normal `ActivityHandler` methods within it for all channels.

Comment: I even extended my Bot class with TeamsActivityHandler, and then I got an unresponsive Bot. I tried a different approach then, like creating a separate class that extends from TeamsActivityHandler, which is instanced by the bot when it receives a ActivityTypes.Invoke message. In that class only if I do this.onInvokeActivity(turnContext); makes handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch() to be called, but no good results obtained either. I still can't figure out how to make Teams receive a simple AdaptiveCard/URL to display in those popups.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm not sure how to best help you. Start fresh with one of the Teams samples (#50-60) and go from there; it works on all channels, you just need to do something in the non-`onTeams*` methods. You need `TeamsActivityHandler` and you only need one class that implements `ActivityHandler`, period.